# Turn string variables into numeric representatives and store the strings elsewhere?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I don't know the best way to describe my problem and I'm just looking for a push in the right direction, or where to start.  **I'd be perfectly happy with an answer that's a very useful link or pseudo code.**

My problem, I have a database that's about to hit the MS Access hard coded 2 GB database limit and I don't want to split the database.

What I think is a possible solution - make the database more efficient in it's data storage. I think, but don't know if this is true, that I could do this by turning some string fields into numeric fields. Stay with me...

For instance:

- My database has several million records of a field we'll call TooLongString
- Each value is about 50 characters
- Every record has a value for this field
- There's only 9 possible values for TooLongString
- Would it decrease my database size to instead store a number that
  represents one of the 9 possible values and store the text value in a small table? (So go from 50 characters to 1 character several million times)

Did I explain my issue correctly? Is my potential solution actually a solution? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You done a compact + repair. And I assume your code + forms etc. is SEPARATE from the tables? Next ensure that “compression” is enabled for most columns. So open up the table(s) in design mode and ensure that compression is turned on for most columns (at least any column more then say 5 chars long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, that would reduce the size of your database.  You could have a second table that holds the nine possible values for "TooLongString" and just store the ID of the appropriate answer  in the main table, as you suggested.  You would then need to join these tables when pulling the data out in order to retrieve the actual text instead of the ID.

I would set up your new table first, then add a new column for the ID into your existing one. As there are only nine possible values, I'd be tempted to just manually run an UPDATE query nine times, e.g. if the first string in your new table is "MyFirstString" with ID 1, you could run "UPDATE existingTableName SET newColumn = 1 WHERE oldColumn = 'MyFirstString'". Do this for each of the nine values then you can remove the old string column from your table at the end.

Comment: Thanks Dan, how would I go about actually converting those values in the main table?

Comment: I would set up your new table first, then add a new column for the ID into your existing one.  As there are only nine possible values, I'd be tempted to just manually run an UPDATE query nine times, e.g. if the first string in your new table is "MyFirstString" with ID 1, you could run "UPDATE existingTableName SET newColumn = 1 WHERE oldColumn = 'MyFirstString'".  Do this for each of the nine values then you can remove the old string column from your table at the end.